# object instantiation - mvc simultaneous connections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object

This is a pretty basic question but just want help understanding how a server interacts with the browser/computer connecting to it.

When a user hits the Create() action it sends the Currentclaim object to the view. Because the _currentclaim variable is null it creates a new object with certain properties. If I load up another browser (IE, Safari) and use the app it isn't a 'fresh start' as _currentclaim has retained the properties that were given to it in the other browser.

```
  public class ClaimsController : Controller
    {

        private static ClaimViewModel _currentclaim;
        private static ClaimViewModel Currentclaim
        {
            get
            {//If _currentclaim is null then create it. Return it.
                if (_currentclaim == null)
                    _currentclaim = GetClaimViewModel();
                return _currentclaim;
            }
            set//set value of Currentclaim. 
            {
                _currentclaim = value;
            }
        }

        public static ClaimViewModel GetClaimViewModel()
        {
            return new ClaimViewModel()
            {
                ClaimID = 101,
                SubmissionUserID = 10,
                DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now,

                LineViewModels = new List<LineViewModel>() {
                    new LineViewModel() {MeetingDate=DateTime.Now,SubCatID=1},
                }
            };
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(Currentclaim);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ClaimViewModel claimvm)
        {   claimvm.SubmissionUserID = Currentclaim.SubmissionUserID;
            claimvm.DateSubmitted = Currentclaim.DateSubmitted;
            _currentclaim = claimvm;
            return View("Summary", Currentclaim);
        }


    }
```

I just want to be reasssured that when a user connects to my web application from wherever it is hosted that his or her session will start with a null object (and not one instantiated by someone else .... if that makes sense)

Comment: Please show the full code of your controller and where are you storing the object. Are you using some static fields or properties?

Comment: Those two browsers are like Chrome and Firefox? Not a second tab in your favourite browser?

Comment: Hi, yes 2 different browsers. Please see amends above.